# mysql slow on simple query

Tags: mysql

I have a simple query `select * from table1 limit 5` on a large table but it stucks at "sending data". There is only one connection.

Here's the `describe` query:

```
+----+-------------+----------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+-----------+----------+-------+
| id | select_type | table          | partitions | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows      | filtered | Extra |
+----+-------------+----------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+-----------+----------+-------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | table1         | NULL       | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 177400355 |   100.00 | NULL  |
+----+-------------+----------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+-----------+----------+-------+
```

And `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE 'innodb%'`

```
+---------------------------------------+------------------------------------+
| Variable_name                         | Value                              |
+---------------------------------------+------------------------------------+
| Innodb_buffer_pool_dump_status        | Dumping of buffer pool not started |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_load_status        | Loaded 139265/260068 pages         |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_resize_status      |                                    |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_data         | 1016643                            |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_bytes_data         | 16656678912                        |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_dirty        | 753432                             |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_bytes_dirty        | 12344229888                        |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_flushed      | 544507                             |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_free         | 7999                               |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_misc         | 23870                              |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_total        | 1048512                            |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_read_ahead_rnd     | 0                                  |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_read_ahead         | 210478                             |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_read_ahead_evicted | 0                                  |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_read_requests      | 234500180                          |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_reads              | 648513                             |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_wait_free          | 0                                  |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_write_requests     | 104348100                          |
| Innodb_data_fsyncs                    | 21149                              |
| Innodb_data_pending_fsyncs            | 0                                  |
| Innodb_data_pending_reads             | 1                                  |
| Innodb_data_pending_writes            | 0                                  |
| Innodb_data_read                      | 29893923328                        |
| Innodb_data_reads                     | 1765288                            |
| Innodb_data_writes                    | 731140                             |
| Innodb_data_written                   | 13111207936                        |
| Innodb_dblwr_pages_written            | 0                                  |
| Innodb_dblwr_writes                   | 0                                  |
| Innodb_log_waits                      | 0                                  |
| Innodb_log_write_requests             | 2982120                            |
| Innodb_log_writes                     | 1646                               |
| Innodb_os_log_fsyncs                  | 1773                               |
| Innodb_os_log_pending_fsyncs          | 0                                  |
| Innodb_os_log_pending_writes          | 0                                  |
| Innodb_os_log_written                 | 1170811392                         |
| Innodb_page_size                      | 16384                              |
| Innodb_pages_created                  | 34                                 |
| Innodb_pages_read                     | 1745291                            |
| Innodb_pages_written                  | 729507                             |
| Innodb_row_lock_current_waits         | 0                                  |
| Innodb_row_lock_time                  | 0                                  |
| Innodb_row_lock_time_avg              | 0                                  |
| Innodb_row_lock_time_max              | 0                                  |
| Innodb_row_lock_waits                 | 0                                  |
| Innodb_rows_deleted                   | 0                                  |
| Innodb_rows_inserted                  | 0                                  |
| Innodb_rows_read                      | 10                                 |
| Innodb_rows_updated                   | 0                                  |
| Innodb_num_open_files                 | 36                                 |
| Innodb_truncated_status_writes        | 0                                  |
| Innodb_available_undo_logs            | 128                                |
+---------------------------------------+------------------------------------+
```

What is wrong?

**Edit:** changed the table name to avoid confusion.

Here is the `my.cnf` setup:

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 16G
innodb_log_buffer_size = 4G
innodb_log_file_size = 4G
innodb_write_io_threads = 32
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 0
innodb_doublewrite = 0
innodb_change_buffer_max_size = 50
innodb_data_file_path = ibdata1:10M:autoextend
query_cache_limit = 0
query_cache_size = 0
query_cache_type = 0
```

Comment: FYI, without an `ORDER BY` or `WHERE` clause, `TOP` is just going to return random rows from the entire table, which seems nonsensical. Are you sure that's what you want?

Comment: Is that the entire query?  Is `table` really a `VIEW`?  Are there any Triggers?

Comment: @J.D. Yes I understand that. But even with such a simple query it takes too long. So  suspect there is something wrong.

Comment: @RickJames Sorry for the confusion. `table` is the just table name by itself. I changed it to `table1` to clear the confusion. Thanks.

Comment: Well part of my point is (and I'm not sure because I'm not versed in reading MySQL execution plans but) is it possible the entire table is being read first before applying the `LIMIT` operator (which is what I meant in my original comment, sorry, not `TOP`). What does `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` show anyway? And to reiterate Rick's point, what type of object is `table1`, a View or a Table?

Comment: How long was it stuck on "sending data" before you gave up?

Comment: @J.D. Thanks. I think `LIMIT` in MySQL is equivalent to `TOP`. And `table1` is a table itself with 177,400,355 rows. I also tried `ORDER BY` an index with `LIMIT` but was still stuck.

Comment: @RickJames I waited for 1 hour which is quite unreasonable for such a simple query.

Comment: I added `my.cnf` in the post. Thanks!

Comment: @cccfran - Hmmmm...  The query is so simple that I see no way for it to take more then even 1 second.  I expect it to read the data's BTree from the start, and quit after sending 5 rows.  (The big number in "Rows" in the EXPLAIN is bogus.)  Another question... Was anything else running when this happened.  (Example: a backup.)

Comment: @J.D. MySQL has a [limit optimization](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/limit-optimization.html) to exit the nested loop as soon as it finds enough matching rows. However, EXPLAIN always shows a row estimate equal to the full number of rows in the table, because it doesn't know how many rows it will have to read before finding some that satisfy any conditions of the WHERE clause (despite there being no conditions in this case).

Comment: @J.D. It won't return _random_ rows, it'll return _arbitrary_ rows. The difference is that it's repeatable. In practice, current versions of InnoDB return rows in index order, for whatever index it reads them from. In this case, a table-scan will read in primary key order.

Comment: @cccfran, Is there anything else about what's running on this server that you haven't mentioned? Resource-intensive applications? Is the load average super high? Is it swapping? What about the storage? Is it super slow or degraded storage, or remote storage, or a USB drive, or something else?

Comment: @BillKarwin Is that guaranteed repeatable though?... I know in SQL Server it's not guaranteed, despite following similar logic.

Comment: @J.D. If the optimizer picks a different index, of course the order may change. And they are free to change the implementation in some future release. It's not guaranteed. What I mean by in practice is that in the current version, that's how it works.

Comment: @BillKarwin Then I think *random* is still suitable of a word (perhaps unpredictable is slightly better fitting or my favorite word - nondeterministic), in addition to arbitrary. Not to be pedantic over linguistics lol.

Answer (score 0):

@cccfran Please set variables 'query_cache_limit = 0' 'query_cache_size = 0' and 'query_cache_type = 0' in [mysqld] section of your mysql server configuration

Comment: Thanks! But it does not really work.

Comment: @cccfran Can you please give the actual query you are trying to run by aliasing the original table/column names?